# Sketch event in Openlayers 3 drawing interaction

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers

For drawing Polygon in OpenLayers 2 we could use as follow:

```
function drawEnd(){
    ...
}

function putPoint(){
    ...
}

function sketchModified(){
    ...
}

function cancel(){
    ...
}

var callBackParams = {
    "done": drawEnd,
    "point": putPoint,
    "modify": sketchModified,
    "cancel": cancel
}

var drawCrtl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {callbacks: callBackParams});
map.addControls([drawCrtl]);
drawCrtl.activate();
```

When we put point to drawing the polygon, the system call `putPoint function`. When mouse move over the map, it call `sketchModified function`. I want to use these two Event in OpenLayers 3. I define my layer as follow:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source
});
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Polygon'
});

drawStart = function(){
    console.log("Salam Bar Mahdi");
}
drawEnd = function(){
    console.log("Ya Mahdi");
}

draw.on('drawstart', drawStart);
draw.on('drawend', drawEnd);
var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, modify, draw]),
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: "Global Imagery",
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms?service=WMS',
          params: {LAYERS: 'world:worldRaster', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
        })
      }),
      vector
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 4
    })
});
```

But in Openlayers 3 I saw only drawEnd and DrawStart Event.

How Can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers v3.5.0 does not easily support the feature you're looking for, but there is a feature currently in development that you can use.

On `ol.interaction.Draw`, you can specify an `ol.interaction.DrawGeometryFunctionType` function to handle updates to the current geometry.

An example I've written up is shown below:

```
var geometryFunction = function (c, g) {
  if (goog.isDef(g)) {
    g.setCoordinates(c);
  } else {
    g = new ol.geom.Polygon(c);
  }

  if (c[0].length > ct) {
    console.log('mouse click coord : ' + c[0][c[0].length - 1]);
    ct = c[0].length;
  } else {
    console.log('mouse move coord : ' + c[0][c[0].length - 1]);
  }

  return g;
}
```

This is pretty much what the [default](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/drawinteraction.js#L200) `geometryFunction` function does, without the new point identification and console logging.

A fully functional example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/1a948faa/2/

Note the following caveats:

- You will have to implement a separate function, or case for different geometry types.
- The code is currently still in development and is thus not stable.  In addition it is subject to change at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your Example only implement `putPoint` function, but I need `sketchModified` too.

Comment: If you run the example, you will see that `geometryFunction` is triggered on both mouseclick and mousemove events.  Given the experimental state of the API, if you need any further functionality than that you will have to work it out for yourself.

Comment: @mortezamalvandi The example has been updated to show you the complete functionality.

Comment: what's `goog`? It error for me

Comment: @Dariush you might want to ask your own question to get an appropriate response, but it sounds like you may either have a projection issue or you aren't using the latest open layers.

Comment: sorry sir. I'm using `ol-3.6.0`. But I use `ol.js` file , you use `ol-debug.js` file .

Comment: Why it error for `ol.js` file?