# Can ESRI JS API show PolyLine as Bezier curve?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, line

Can `ESRI JS API` somehow show `PolyLine` as `Bezier Curve`?

If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Do you have the points to your curve, or do you want the API to also generate your line points?

Comment: I use `ESRI JS API`. I can show the line here as `PolyLine`. Is there a way to render it as `Bezier`? Sure I have the points coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw `bezier curve`, and you can get all points of line, perhaps [Using cubiccurve in OpenLayers 2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153265/using-cubiccurve-in-openlayers-2) can help you.

Comment: Is that apart of ESRI JS API?

Comment: You can try it!