# How to create a circle in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have tried to create a circle of desired range using following code but not working. Please guide me.

```
function createBuffer(lat, lon, range) {

var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill : new ol.style.Fill({
    color : 'yellow',
    opacity : 0.6,
    color : 'rgba(255,255,204,0.3)'
}),
stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
    width : 2,
    // color: 'rgba(255, 100, 50, 0.8)'
    color : 'red',
    radius : 1
}),
image : new ol.style.Circle({
    fill : new ol.style.Fill({
    // color: 'rgba(55, 200, 150, 0.5)'
    color : 'rgba(51, 204, 255,0.3)'
}),
stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
    width : 1,
    color : 'blue'
    // color:'rgb(230, 184, 0,0)'
}),
radius : 3
}),
  });
var  features = [];
var point = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lon)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:4326'),range*1210);
console.log(point.getCenter());
console.log(point);  

// Features
var pointFeature = new ol.Feature(point);
features.push(pointFeature);

// Source and vector layer
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: features
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source : vectorSource,
    style : style
});
map.renderSync();
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
}
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly (to make it readable), and provide information about you view config (primarily its projection), I'll give it a go.

Comment: I am trying to make a circle in this code but not working for me.In other project same code is working.

Comment: Well, as I said: rewrite your question with readable code (fix the indentation) and information about your view.

Comment: I want to make a circle of desired radius at specific lat lon,

Comment: look at [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153265/using-cubiccurve-in-openlayers-2/157234#157234)

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ example. we also need to see how you define your map.

Comment: my map is coming from geoserver which is localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a simple listener on double click that adds a circle to the map:

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) {
  var coordinate = map.getEventCoordinate(e);
  vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle(coordinate, dist)));
});
```

The distance `dist` can be defined elsewhere.

Check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrocha/5yxtsf31/). It has a running example. When you double click on the map, a circle is created. If you want to change the circle radius, change the combobox.

If you want to create a buffer around an existing point, it is not much more complicated. I've created another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrocha/ztk2u3pb/), where you already have a layer with 4 cities. If you click on a city, the buffer is created.

Be aware that the web mercator maybe IS NOT THE BEST PROJECTION to create circles. Make sure you understand the [web mercator fallacy](https://glenbambrick.com/tag/web-mercator/).