# How to define feature modify event in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, modify-interaction, modify-interaction-event

I'm using [OpenLayers-3.8.2](http://openlayers.org). I have modify interaction as follows:

```
selectedInteraction = ... 
modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
   features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});
```

I want to define an event that when a point of feature change, it fires. Something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149210/sketch-event-in-openlayers-3-drawing-interaction), but NOT for drawing, for modifying.

How do I do?

Comment: The interaction automatically fires an event, if a feature handled by the interaction is modified. Use `modifyInteraction.on('modifyend', function (evt) {//your code});`

Comment: This fire when `modify` end. But I want to fire when a feature is sketched.

Comment: I'm afraid, with the modify interaction, you can only work with the `modifystart`, and `modifyend` events related  to sketching.

Answer (score 1):

On `modifystart` you need to listen for `change:geometry`event on the feature then on `modifyend` you remove this listener.

Answer (score 1):

there is an event on the select interaction, that fires when you modify a feature and click outside of it:

```
selectedInteraction.getFeatures().on('add', function(e) {
    e.element.on('change', function(e) {
    //and here e.target is the feature that has been modified
    });
});
```