# Openlayers drawing interaction geometryFunction

Tags: openlayers, geometry, map-drawing, draw-interaction

Can anyone help me to convert this function so that it is not dependant on the ol3-debug file as I don't know quite what is replaced upon build. The function works but only in debug mode.

It is in reference to this question: [Sketch event in Openlayers 3 drawing interaction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149210/sketch-event-in-openlayers-3-drawing-interaction)

The intention is that it will allow me to display each features co-ords as they are drawn on-screen.

```
geometryFunction: function (c, g) {
        if (goog.isDef(g)) {
            g.setCoordinates(c);
        } else {
            g = new ol.geom.LineString(c);
        }
        if (c[0].length > ct) {
            console.log('click coord : ' + c[0][c[0].length - 1]);
            ct = c[0].length;
        } else {
            console.log('move coord : ' + c[0][c[0].length - 1]);
        }

        return g;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vectorSource,
    type: "LineString",
    geometryFunction: function(coords, geom) {
        if (!geom) {
            geom = new ol.geom.LineString(null);
        }
        console.info(coords);
        geom.setCoordinates(coords);
        return geom;
    }
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152646/50718

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8b322285/

Comment: Thanks Jonatas, that makes perfect sense. Unfortunately I still can't implement this in the way I need. I currently have a function triggered by the drawend event which will print out a list of the coordinates transformed into lon lat pairs.
When I try to incorporate this into thegeometry function it replicates each value approx. 4 times. I think I need to register each click event but I don't know how to do this. My example is below.

Comment: lns.on('drawend', function (e) {
        var lnsPoints = [];
        for (var i = 0; coords.length > i; i++) {
            var coord = coords[i];
            var coordTrans = ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
            lnsPoints.push(coordTrans);
    }
    for (var i = 0; lnsPoints.length > i; i++) {
                    var pointPair = lnsPoints[i];
                    var lon = pointPair[1];
                    var lat = pointPair[0];
                    var pointList = "html to build list";

                    $('#lns_p').append(pointList);
                }
    });

Comment: See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8b322285/

Comment: Again, many thanks for your attention Jonatas. This is pretty much working as it should now except that the double-click 'drawend' event will duplicate the last coordinates. Is it possible to 'catch' the drawend event within the geometry function? I've adapted your fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/dvmac/ughxwm4n/

Comment: In fact I've just stumbled upon your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ots444of/ regarding appending coordinates. This is exactly the kind of functionality I'm looking for so I'm wondering if I should start with an empty linestring on my layer and append coords and push to my ul simultaneously?

Comment: I'm a bit lost of what is missing to this question's scope.

Comment: I'm sorry Jonatas, My comment after your fiddle is related to my main question. My fiddle demonstrates that my function works but at the end, the last point is replicated and I don't know how to avoid this? The second comment is something I found later but would like to emulate. I would like to be able to draw a linestring point-by-point and populate my list with the features so I was wondering if the approach in your second fiddle could be made to achieve this? Sorry if this is confusing and thanks for your attention. I can find meaningful examples of this more complicated functionality.

Comment: Well, to remove the last (duplicate) point from the DOM just use jQuery (since you already using) to do this. And I ask you to create another question about this another approach.